# custom labels for choropleth map using ggplot scale_colour_stepsn

Tags: r, ggplot2

Am getting the error when adding a label to my scale_colour_stepsn*

```
Error in `check_breaks_labels()`:
! `breaks` and `labels` must have the same length
```

*am using this to specific the colours of my bins rather than putting my data on a scale/gradient

Have looked around for a solution but they all seem to be for characters, whereas my data is numerical (continuous) and I'm not sure how to apply those solutions to my situation

Here's my code:

```
my_colours<- c("#00B050", "#92D050", "#FFFFB2", "#FED976", "#FEB24C")
aus_shp<- read_sf("~/map files/STE_2016_AUST.shp")
aus_shp$ent_gentob<- c(4.3,11.9,8.3,6.1,14.5,0.0,16.8,4.6,NA)
ggplot(data = aus_shp) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = ent_gentob))+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93, .93),
        legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
        legend.box.just = "right",
        legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))+
  scale_colour_stepsn(
    colours =  my_colours,
    breaks = c(1,5,10,15,20),
    labels = c(">1%", "1-<5%", "5-<10%", "10-<15%", "15-<20%"),
    aesthetics = "fill",
    name = "% R"
    )
```

I need to replicate this chart several times for different numerical variables using the same scale

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there are only four breaks in your legend (the last one `20` gets dropped), whereas you provide five labels. One option to fix that would be to set the `limits` to include the `20` as the upper bound.

Also note that there is a `scale_fill_stepsn`.

Using some fake example data base on the `nc` shapefile from the `sf` package.

```r
my_colours <- c("#00B050", "#92D050", "#FFFFB2", "#FED976", "#FEB24C")
aus_shp <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
aus_shp$ent_gentob <- rep_len(c(4.3, 11.9, 8.3, 6.1, 14.5, 0.0, 16.8, 4.6, NA), nrow(aus_shp))

library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot(data = aus_shp) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = ent_gentob)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    # legend.position = c(.93, .93),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6)
  )

base +
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    colours = my_colours,
    breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20),
    limits = c(0, 20),
    labels = c("<1%", "1-<5%", "5-<10%", "10-<15%", "15-<20%"),
    name = "% R"
  )
```

[image]

However, personally I would switch to a discrete fill scale for this type of legend by binning the data manually. Also note that the color assignment is different from the one you get by relying on `scale_fill_stepsn`. IMHO this is one more reason to do some manual work.

```r
aus_shp$ent_gentob_bins <- cut(aus_shp$ent_gentob,
  breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 5, 10, 15, 20),
  right = FALSE
)

ggplot(data = aus_shp) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = ent_gentob_bins)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    # legend.position = c(.93, .93),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colours,
    limits = levels(aus_shp$ent_gentob_bins),
    labels = c("<1%", "1-<5%", "5-<10%", "10-<15%", "15-<20%"),
    name = "% R",
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA), reverse = TRUE)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan that worked!*

*eventually, first I had to increase the number of colours as it spewed out the error "Insufficient values in manual scale. 8 needed but only 5 provided". So I upped the number of colours in my scale (which works for future charts anyway where the % R will increase for other maps)